# Can`t iterate over set

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

I need help. When trying iterate over a set I get the following error:

> Error 1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>' to
>   'compound_objectNS::Compound_object *'    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory 208

I got the following code:
extract from file "compound_object.cpp":

```
typedef compound_objectNS::Compound_object OBJECT
    bool OBJECT::operator== (const Compound_object &object) const
    {
        return this == &object;
    }

    bool OBJECT::operator< (const Compound_object &object) const
    {
        return this->m_numberOfObject < object.m_numberOfObject;
    }
```

here to allow set to sort it elements I override operators "==" and " <"

client file:

```
for (objectImitatorNS::set<compound_objectNS::Compound_object*>::iterator it = Objects->begin();
        it != Objects->end(); ++it)
    {
        this->m_imitatedObjects->insert(it);
    }
```

As I figured out error is raised when line

> this->m_imitatedObjects->insert(it)

executed.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::set::insert` (the version that takes one parameter) does not take an iterator. It takes a value. [See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/). You can try:

```
this->m_imitatedObjects->insert(*it);
```

Comment: `insert` could indeed "take an iterator", just not in the overload that the OP is looking for... (e.g. `insert(it, 0)` would have "worked").

Comment: Yes, of course. I've edited to say that the version that takes one parameter doesn't take an iterator.

Answer (score 4):

Say `this->m_imitatedObjects->insert(*it);`. You're inserting *values*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert value not iterator obj.